# Transfer a customer to your reseller account

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-api-java-client, google-reseller-api

I am trying to transfer a customer domain to my reseller account.
I have transfer token generated

In the below screen, if I give the domain and transfer token, I will have a customer created with all the details.


How to do this using the API

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/customers/insert

I am trying to create passing the domain and authtoken, it shows me the resource already exists error.

Any help will be much appreciated

[image]

Comment: You can't order the same customer account twice. Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/customers/insert) `Before ordering a new customer account, establish whether the customer account already exists using the` [customers.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/customers/get). In order to help you, please describe your scenario and what you are trying to achieve but you cannot.

Comment: @fullfine, my scenario is to tranfer an existing customer to my reseller account. I have to do it using apis

Comment: If the *resource already exists*, you have already transferred your customer. Now, you need to transfer the subscription. Find more information about it: [Transfer a customer to your reseller account](https://support.google.com/channelservices/answer/9547629?hl=en#zippy=), [Reseller API: Transfer a subscription](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/manage_subscriptions#transfer_a_subscription).

Comment: @fullfine, yeah, my question here is how to transfer the customer using API

Answer (score 0):

To transfer a customer and its subscriptions you have to use the methods [customers.insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/customers/insert) and [subscriptions.insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/subscriptions/insert). You can find more information in the following documentation: [Transfer a subscription](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/manage_subscriptions#transfer_a_subscription) and [Transfer a customer to your account](https://support.google.com/channelservices/answer/9547629?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctransfer-the-customer-and-place-an-order)

Comment: There is a new release of APIs, https://cloud.google.com/channel/docs
I want to do the above operations using this